# Battery loading state on command line?

Tags: command-line, battery

Sometimes the energy status applet on my gnome panel suddenly disappears.

Is there a simple command to print the loading state of the battery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check battery status using terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/69556/how-to-check-battery-status-using-terminal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different methods for this:
First, you could install the package [acpi](http://packages.ubuntu.com/acpi) [image: Install acpi] and run it like to:

```
acpi -b
```

It will show you the battery's current capacity and whether it's charging, discharging and how long it will last/take to be recharged if charging.

If you don't want to install new packages, there's also the proc filesystem to query: `cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state`, which will give you the following output:

```
present:                 yes
capacity state:          ok
charging state:          charged
present rate:            1 mA
remaining capacity:      7800 mAh
present voltage:         12062 mV
```

for more details on your battery, check `cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/info`

```
present:                 yes
design capacity:         7800 mAh
last full capacity:      2898 mAh
battery technology:      rechargeable
design voltage:          11100 mV
design capacity warning: 780 mAh
design capacity low:     236 mAh
cycle count:          0
capacity granularity 1:  78 mAh
capacity granularity 2:  78 mAh
model number:            DELL WK3798
serial number:           1226
battery type:            LION
OEM info:                Sanyo
```

Answer (score 4):

```
cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state
```

Will give you the remaining capacity.

```
cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/info
```

To check the maximum capacity, both last and designed.

Note that BAT0 is a name that can change between computer models.

Comment: Good answer, thank you.  Using `cat /proc/acpi/battery/*/state` as my battery is named BAT1 and I don't see many people having another battery present.

Answer (score 1):

You could execute `gnome-power-statistics` just to see in the gui and help you with the panel problem (Just to add to the help). The correct answer would be:

1. Go to console and `cd /proc/acpi/battery`
2. Type `ls` to see what is the name of your Battery, could be BAT0, BAT1, etc..
3. If it is for example BAT0 Type `cat BAT0/state`
4. If you need extra info type cat `BAT0/info`

You can also install **acpi** `sudo apt-get install acpi`

then type `acpi -b` in console

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to write a script to check the battery level stuff.
When I was toying with ruby [I wrote one here](http://paste.mitechie.com/show/221/)

It does require the gem for ansi/code for the coloring at the terminal.

[This is kind of a bash alternative that I used at one time](http://paste.mitechie.com/show/222/)

The stuff with the BAT0 vs BAT1 is that on my laptop I had a second battery in the DVD drive bay so there were actually two to check.