# How do I check the battery's status via the terminal?

Tags: command-line, battery

I would like a command that displays the battery status in the terminal.

Comment: `$ upower -i $(upower -e | grep 'BAT') | grep -E "state|to\ full|percentage"`

Answer (score 461):

The below command outputs a lot status and statistical information about the battery. The `/org/...` path can be found with the command `upower -e` (`--enumerate`).

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

Example output:

```
  native-path:          /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0
  vendor:               NOTEBOOK
  model:                BAT
  serial:               0001
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Thu Feb  9 18:42:15 2012 (1 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    energy:              22.3998 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         52.6473 Wh
    energy-full-design:  62.16 Wh
    energy-rate:         31.6905 W
    voltage:             12.191 V
    time to full:        57.3 minutes
    percentage:          42.5469%
    capacity:            84.6964%
    technology:          lithium-ion
  History (charge):
    1328809335  42.547  charging
    1328809305  42.020  charging
    1328809275  41.472  charging
    1328809245  41.008  charging
  History (rate):
    1328809335  31.691  charging
    1328809305  32.323  charging
    1328809275  33.133  charging
```

You could use tools like grep to get just the information you want from all that output.

One simple way: piping the above command into

```
grep -E "state|to\ full|percentage"
```

outputs:

```
state:               charging
time to full:        57.3 minutes
percentage:          42.5469%
```

If you would often like to run that command, then you could make a Bash alias for the whole command. Example:

```
alias bat='upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0| grep -E "state|to\ full|percentage"'
```

Add that to the end of your .bashrc file, and you can type 'bat' any time, in the terminal.

There is also a `upower -d` (`--dump`) command that shows information for all available power resources such as laptop batteries, external mice, etc.

Comment: `upower --enumerate` can be useful if you are not sure how to use `upower`.

Comment: @landroni And the shorthand option is `upower -e`, that command lists the available paths for `upower -i ...`. If you are lazy and just want a list of all devices, use `upower -d` (`upower --dump`).

Comment: Indeed. I think this would be a useful addition to the answer itself, as when I first tried to use `upower` I immediately got lost.

Comment: @landroni Good point, I have updated the answer. Feel free to edit it if you have more related additions.

Comment: Another one-liner could be `upower -i $(upower -e | grep BAT) | grep --color=never -E "state|to\ full|to\ empty|percentage"`

Comment: I ran the above command and it says `updated:              Thursday 01 January 1970 05:30:00 AM IST (1531404045 seconds ago)`. Any ideas how can I update this information?

Comment: Each one of the 327 up-votes is well deserved. **Note:** replace `BAT0` with `BAT1` if answer doesn't work for you.

Comment: ⚠️ `percentage` is relative to `energy-full`, and once `energy-full` is (a lot) smaller than `energy-full-design` you get misleading results. My 5yo laptop has about 80% `capacity` so I ran into forced shutdowns because my alert uses `percentage` and triggered too late. `energy / energy-full-design` is, arguably, more helpful to decide when to _start_ charging; `percentage` is more useful for deciding when to _stop_.

Answer (score 207):

**A friendly reminder**: since Linux kernel **2.6.24** using `/proc` to store ACPI info has been **discouraged** and **deprecated**.

Now we are encouraged to use -> `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0`.

UPDATE: Linux 3.19 and onwards, we should look at the following directory -> `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/`

For example, checking capacity & status running

Linux 4.20

```bsh
# uname -a
Linux netbook 4.20.1-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jan 9 20:25:43 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/capacity
99
# cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status
Charging
```

and

Linux 5.9

```bsh
# uname -a
Linux netbook 5.9.1-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat, 17 Oct 2020 13:30:37 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/capacity
100
# cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status
Full
```

Comment: Specifically, `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity` seems to show the current charge percentage.

Comment: *Deprecated…* does it still work?

Comment: +1, this should be the accepted answer, since it doesn't rely on extra software that might not be installed and is not needed to answer this question. @neverMind9: I don't know what you mean `/proc` is deprecated but `/sys` works perfectly for me, even in kernel 4.20.

Comment: Terry maybe on Arch they start from BAT1 but seems that on Ubuntu always is BAT0, at least nowadays, and AFAIK almost all portable devices uses just one battery (I don't know why `acpi -b` or `acpitool -B` output three).

Comment: Not only this should be the accepter answer, but retrieving the data can be achieved by using any programming language that has a `read` function like in PHP `$capacity = trim(file_get_contents("/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity"));` making it super easy and not dependent of any external dependencies.

Comment: @PabloBianchi I've seen `BAT1` since I installed Arch on the netbook ;-) It makes more sense for the broader audience that battery start from 0 instead of 1, I agree with you.

Comment: Is this POSIX compatible, or Linux only?

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick Only tested on Linux, so I reckon it is Linux only. Don't know how other UNIX-like systems, e.g. Solaris, BSD flavours represent battery (may need to leverage `sysctl` to make it POSIX compatible).

Comment: ⚠️ `capacity` here is _not_ what "capacity" usually means (e.g. in the output of `upower`). In `upower`, it's called `percentage`. That's important because `capacity` is relative to `energy_full`, and once `energy_full` is (a lot) smaller than `energy_full_design` you get misleading results. My 5yo laptop has about 80% `energy_full / energy_full_design` so I ran into forced shutdowns because my alert uses `capacity` and triggered too late.

Answer (score 90):

First install `acpi` by running this command,

```
sudo apt-get install acpi
```

Then run:

```
acpi
```

---

**Sample output:**

```
Battery 0: Discharging, 61%, 01:10:12 remaining
```

---

Or for a more verbose output that constantly updates:

```
watch --interval=5 acpi -V
```

Output:

```
Every 5.0s: acpi -V                                     Wed Jan  8 15:45:35 2014

Battery 0: Full, 100%
Adapter 0: on-line
Thermal 0: ok, 44.0 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 0 switches to mode critical at temperature 127.0 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 1 switches to mode hot at temperature 127.0 degrees C
Cooling 0: intel_powerclamp no state information available
Cooling 1: pkg-temp-0 no state information available
Cooling 2: LCD 100 of 100
Cooling 3: LCD 100 of 100
Cooling 4: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 5: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 6: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 7: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 8: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 9: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 10: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 11: Processor 0 of 10
```

Comment: I run Lubuntu, with Ubuntu 18.04. After installing acpi, I get command not found.

Comment: acpi tool is deprecated as from kernel 2.6.24 as noted on other answers.

Comment: FWIW it's Sept 2021,  I am running Ubuntu 21 (pre-relese) and this worked great.

Comment: This is the way to go for me on Debian

Comment: I think I understood wrongly something on ACPI deprecation, it's discouraged to use `/proc` to store the data, but your command has been updated to load from `/sys`.

Comment: ⚠️ Same note as for `upower` and `/sys/class/power_supply`: The percentage given is relative to the remaining battery capacity, not the designed capacity. Once your battery capacity degrades, the given percentage can be misleading, esp. when running low!

Answer (score 34):

Thanks to @Wilf this works on my Ubuntu 17.10 on Lenovo Yoga 720:

```
upower -i $(upower -e | grep '/battery') | grep --color=never -E "state|to\ full|to\ empty|percentage"
```

Output:

```
state:               fully-charged
percentage:          100%
```

Or just the numeric value with this one liner

```
upower -i $(upower -e | grep '/battery') | grep --color=never -E percentage|xargs|cut -d' ' -f2|sed s/%//
```

Comment: On **Fedora 23** I had to grep for `battery` instead of `BAT` to make it work. I found that with `upower --enumerate`.

Comment: grep for `battery` works in Ubuntu too, so I changed it from `BAT`

Comment: If multiple batteries are presented (i.e. thinkpad T480), only first (internal) is shown.

Comment: I set this up with the `watch` command so I can break in my new batteries properly.

Comment: @Lubo you should have separate paths for each power device. Mine shows me LCD screen and USB power, too - try `upower -e` to enumerate (list) all the paths to different devices, then use the path to specify which one from which you want to read properties after the option flag.  E.g. `upower -i /path/to/your/device`.  Or check them all out in a `for` loop:  `for i in $(upower -e); do upower -i $i; done`

Comment: @AveryFreeman thanks. I have ended up using `tlp-stat -b` and `acpitool`. Your approach is definitely worth of effort also. I have tried it now and it works. Perhaps I will finally make some script using it.

Answer (score 32):

It's enough to type the command

> `acpi`

For detailed information you can type

> `acpi -V`

I didn't have to install any packages before.

System:
Debian 7.2 64bit

Comment: How dis this not a duplicate to this? https://askubuntu.com/a/221492/830570 or https://askubuntu.com/a/47970/830570 ?

Answer (score 22):

[Here](http://www.go2linux.org/laptop-battery-status-with-linux-console-command-acpi) is an article on a package that can check your battery life at the command line.

Basically, all you have to do is:

```
sudo apt-get install acpi
acpi -V
```

Comment: `acpi` tool is deprecated as from kernel 2.6.24 as [morhook](https://askubuntu.com/users/170833/morhook) stated among others

Answer (score 20):

Maybe you can try:

`cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state`

`cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/info`

Comment: using `/proc` to store ACPI info has been discouraged and deprecated since 2.6.24. Now it's in `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0`.

Answer (score 17):

I'm a little late to the party but here's my little contribution. Based on the previous answers , I have made a simple script batpower:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Description: Battery  charge in percentage

grep POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent
```

The output for executing this ( ./batpower ) is going to be something like this:

```
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=23
```

N.B. : the batery number may be different for you, in my case it is BAT1, but you can always find it out by cd'ing to /sys/class/power_supply   or as Lekensteyn mentioned through upower -e

My machine : Ubuntu 13.10 , 3.11.0

Replace **BAT1** in the above bash code to **BAT0** if you have older version Ubuntu i.e. 13.04 or later.

**IMPROVED SCRIPT:** Since my original post, I've made a small improvement to the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Description: Battery  charge in percentage

if [ -f /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent ]
    then grep POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent

else echo "Battery isn't present"

fi
```

As always, pay attention to spaces with bash. This is all self explanatory. If battery is present, it will show up, if not - the script will tell you so. Now, go to your .bashrc file and add $(batpower) to your prompt. Here's mine promt:

```
PS1='[$(batpower)]\n${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}[*\u@Ubuntu*]:\w\$ '
```

Update your terminal or open new tab or window, and now you can monitor battery charge constantly in terminal ! including tty ! May the scripting be praised !
[image]

Comment: You need to check for `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0` and `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1` ... It can be either. And you should use that path (`/sys/class/power_supply/BAT#`).

Comment: In my Ubuntu 12.04 netbook (after changing to BAT0), I don't seem to get a POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY line.  It looks like I could calculate it though, from the POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL and POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_NOW values.

Comment: Upvoted but Batman (Battery Manager) subconsciously has a nicer ring to it than Batpower :) On a serious note it's interesting you were writing in AskUbuntu in 2014 and how different you are today.

Comment: @WinEunuuuchs2Unix Yes, I've changed somewhat since I started, learned a few new tricks. batman would have a nice ring to it but it is likely copyrighted ;)

Answer (score 10):

You can do it without installing any extra packages:

```
$ echo $((100*$(sed -n "s/remaining capacity: *\(.*\) m[AW]h/\1/p" /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state)/$(sed -n "s/last full capacity: *\(.*\) m[AW]h/\1/p" /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/info)))%
94%
```

This command is lifted from [byobu's source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~kirkland/byobu/trunk/view/1340/usr/lib/byobu/battery). It might be a good candidate for a [Bash alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias).

Comment: +1 from me! CLI FTW. If you have 2 battery's change BAT0 for BAT1 :)

Comment: Is discourage since 2.6.24, we should use `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/`

Answer (score 10):

You can either type :

```
$ acpi -i
Battery 0: Discharging, 98%, 02:51:14 remaining
Battery 0: design capacity 4400 mAh, last full capacity 3733 mAh = 84%
```

or

```
$ upower -i $(upower -e | grep BAT)
  native-path:          BAT0
  model:                PA5109U-1BRS
  serial:               FA80
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              lun. 07 janv. 2019 03:54:18 CET (24 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    energy:              39,521 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         40,328 Wh
    energy-full-design:  47,52 Wh
    energy-rate:         13,856 W
    voltage:             10,8 V
    time to empty:       2,9 hours
    percentage:          98%
    capacity:            84,8632%
    technology:          lithium-ion
  History (charge):
    1546829628  98,000  discharging
    1546829593  99,000  discharging
  History (rate):
    1546829658  13,856  discharging
    1546829628  14,752  discharging
    1546829597  4,806   discharging
    1546829594  2,678   discharging
```

or with the distrib's inxi package (more up to date from the [inxi official source code here](https://github.com/smxi/inxi))

```
$ inxi -Bxxx
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 37.4 Wh condition: 37.4/47.5 Wh (79%) volts: 10.8/10.8 model: PA5109U-1BRS type: Li-ion 
           serial: FA80 status: Full
```

Answer (score 8):

This did the job for me in ubuntu 14.04:

```
cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity
```

Comment: `cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT?/capacity` would be a better idea, since it might be `BAT1` instead of `BAT0`.

Answer (score 7):

Run the following command in a terminal for getting detailed info:

```
cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/info
```

If you just want the state do:

```
cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state
```

Comment: This [has been discouraged](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69556/how-do-i-check-the-batterys-status-via-the-terminal/102863#comment389649_69632) in the other identical answer.

Comment: no such path like `/proc/acpi/battery/`

Answer (score 7):

Install acpi, then use `watch` to continously monitor thru command line.

E.g.

`watch --interval=5 acpi -V`

will show the information such as below and will update every 5 seconds.

> Battery 0: Full, 100%, rate information unavailable
>   Battery 0: design capacity 6000 mAh, last full capacity 3424 mAh = 57%

Question is why would someone do this?
Well, I have a laptop with broken LCD screen that I am now using as my bittorrent box.

Answer (score 4):

I was going to suggest `acpi` but after reading it's not working in 11.10, I had an idea.

Please type this in your terminal:
`ls /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0`  or `BAT1`

If you get a "file or directory not found" then this isn't going to work.

But, if it lists files, then here's a script *[paste it into /usr/games/ or other directory in $PATH, and run `sudo chmod +x /usr/games/batterypercent`, or whatever you name it]* that I just wrote for you that will give you an estimate battery percentage [See below]:

**(Note, if not already installed, install the program `calc` from the repo: `sudo apt-get install apcalc`)**

```
#!/bin/bash
math() { calc -d "$@"|tr -d ~; }
cd /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0;
max=$(grep 'design capacity:' info|awk '{print $3}')
current=$(grep 'remaining capacity:' state|awk '{print $3}')
percent=$(math "($current / $max) * 100");
echo $(echo $percent|cut -d. -f1)%
```

I have tested this script on my laptop. I say *estimate* above because `acpi` shows 93% battery, and my script shows 90% battery, so try this script against your GUI battery percentage, and see how off it is.  In my case, it seems to be consistently 3% lower than  acpi's percentage.  In that case, you can add this line right before the last line: `percent=$((percent + 3))`, where "3" is the percentage it's low by.

**In my lenovo, the battery is listed as BAT1, try that too. (12.04 LTS)

Comment: Matt, tried your suggestion, got a "No file or directory"

Comment: Argh.. okay, I'm almost positive this is **why** `acpi` doesn't work, because I guess 11.10 doesn't support your laptop's ACPI functions as well [battery, etc].  I think I've experienced something like this when upgrading in the past.  I'm still on 11.04 though.  Sorry that this didn't work for ya :(

Comment: So, just curious, can you paste the output of `ls /proc/acpi/` ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Similar script without calc or apcalc:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0;
max=$(grep 'design capacity:' info|awk '{print $3}')
current=$(grep 'remaining capacity:' state|awk '{print $3}')
percent=$(expr $current"00" / $max )
echo -e "Current capacity: \t$current"
echo -e "Max capacity:  \t$max"
echo -e "Percent: \t\t$percent"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I use. It just looks at the diff between full charge and current charge as well as seeing if the charge is dropping in which case it uses notify to alert the user.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# experimental battery discharge alerter
#
nsecs=3 # loop sleep time between readings
#
ful=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full)
#
oldval=0
while true
do
  cur=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now)
  dif="$((ful - cur))"
  slope="$((cur - oldval))"
  if [ "$slope" -lt 0 ]
  then
    echo "*** discharging!"
    notify-send -u critical -i "notification-message-IM" "discharging"
  fi
 oldval=$cur
 sleep $nsecs
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't help everyone, but it did me - I use [byobu](http://byobu.co/) whenever I am using a terminal, and battery is one of the options for the status notifications bar.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple run: `upower -i $(upower -e | grep BAT)`

```
> upower -i $(upower -e | grep BAT)
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               SMP
  model:                L19M3PF7
  serial:               3223
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sun 05 Mar 2023 02:33:38 PM EET (21 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       low
    energy:              5.45 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         37.33 Wh
    energy-full-design:  45 Wh
    energy-rate:         16.219 W
    voltage:             10.82 V
    charge-cycles:       917
    time to empty:       20.1 minutes
    percentage:          14%
    capacity:            82.9556%
    technology:          lithium-polymer
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1678019588  14.000  discharging
  History (rate):
    1678019618  16.219  discharging
    1678019588  14.814  discharging
    1678019558  13.941  discharging
    1678019528  12.350  discharging
```

Answer (score -4):

```
cat /proc/acpi/ac_adapter/AC/state
```

Comment: not sure what you're talking about here. running it in the terminal gave `cat: /proc/acpi/ac_adapter/AC0/state: No such file or directory`