# Battery life starts at 2:30 hrs (99%), but less than 1 minute later is only 1:30 hrs (99%)

Tags: power-management, battery

After searching this and other forums, I haven't seen this same issue listed anywhere for Ubuntu 12.

Prior to installing Ubuntu 12.10, my Netbook (Acer AspireOne D250, SATA HDD) was consistently getting 2:30-3 hrs battery life under Windows XP Home, SP3. However, immediately after installing Ubuntu 12.10, the battery life starts out at 2:30 hrs (99%), but less than 1 minute later suddenly drops to 1:30 hrs (99%), which seems very odd. It could be a complete coincidence that the battery is suddenly flaky at the exact same moment that Ubuntu 12.10 was installed, but that doesn't seem likely.

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu, so I don't have much experience tweaking/trouble-shooting yet. Here's what I've tried so far:

- enabled laptop mode (sudo su, then  echo 5 > /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode) and checked that it is running when the A/C adapter is unplugged, but it doesn't seem to have made any noticeable difference in battery life,
- installed Jupiter, but it didn't work and messed up the system, so I had to uninstall it,
- disabled bluetooth (wifi is still on b/c it is necessary), set the screen to lowest brightness, etc.,
- run through at least 1 full power cycle (running until the netbook shut itself off due to critical battery) and have been using it normally (sometimes plugged in, often unplugged until the battery gets very low) for a week since installing Ubuntu 12.10.
- installed powertop, but have no idea how to interpret its results.

Here are the results of **acpi -b**:

1. w/ A/C adapter: Battery 0: Full, 100%
2. immediately after unplugging: Battery 0: Discharging, **99%, 02:30:20** remaining
3. 1 minute after unplugging: Battery 0: Discharging, **99%, 01:37:49** remaining
4. 2-3 minutes after unplugging: Battery 0: Discharging, 95%, 01:33:01 remaining
5. 10 minutes after unplugging: Battery 0: Discharging, 85%, 01:13:38 remaining

Results of **cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent**:

1. w/ A/C adapter:

   > POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT0
   > POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Full
   > POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
   > POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=0
   > POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=10800000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=12136000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CURRENT_NOW=773000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL_DESIGN=4500000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL=1956000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_NOW=1956000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=UM08B32
   > POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=SANYO
   > POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=
2. immediately after unplugging:

   > POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT0
   > POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Discharging
   > POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
   > POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=0
   > POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=10800000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=11886000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CURRENT_NOW=773000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL_DESIGN=4500000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL=1956000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_NOW=1937000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=UM08B32
   > POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=SANYO
   > POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=
3. 1 minute later:

   > POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT0
   > POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Discharging
   > POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
   > POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=0
   > POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=10800000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=11728000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CURRENT_NOW=1174000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL_DESIGN=4500000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL=1956000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_NOW=1937000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=UM08B32
   > POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=SANYO
   >  
   > POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=
4. 2-3 minutes later:

   > POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT0
   > POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Discharging
   > POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
   > POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=0
   > POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=10800000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=11583000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CURRENT_NOW=1209000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL_DESIGN=4500000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL=1956000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_NOW=1878000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=UM08B32
   > POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=SANYO 
   > POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=
5. 10 minutes later:

   > POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT0
   > POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Discharging
   > POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
   > POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=0
   > POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=10800000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=11230000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CURRENT_NOW=1239000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL_DESIGN=4500000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL=1956000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_NOW=1644000
   > POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=UM08B32
   > POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=SANYO 
   > POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=

Results of **upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0**:

1. w/ A/C adapter:

   > native-path: /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:02/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0
   >   vendor:               SANYO
   >   model:                UM08B32
   >   power supply:         yes
   >   updated:              Tue Nov 27 15:24:58 2012 (823 seconds ago)
   >   has history:          yes
   >   has statistics:       yes
   >   battery
   >     present:             yes
   >     rechargeable:        yes
   >     state:               fully-charged
   >     energy:              21.1248 Wh
   >     energy-empty:        0 Wh
   >     energy-full:         21.1248 Wh
   >     energy-full-design:  48.6 Wh
   >     energy-rate:         8.3484 W
   >     voltage:             12.173 V
   >     percentage:          100%
   >     capacity:            43.4667%
   >     technology:          lithium-ion
2. immediately after unplugging:

   > native-path: /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:02/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0
   >   vendor:               SANYO
   >   model:                UM08B32
   >   power supply:         yes
   >   updated:              Tue Nov 27 15:41:25 2012 (1 seconds ago)
   >   has history:          yes
   >   has statistics:       yes
   >   battery
   >     present:             yes
   >     rechargeable:        yes
   >     state:               discharging
   >     energy:              20.9196 Wh
   >     energy-empty:        0 Wh
   >     energy-full:         21.1248 Wh
   >     energy-full-design:  48.6 Wh
   >     energy-rate:         8.3484 W
   >     voltage:             11.86 V
   >     time to empty:       2.5 hours
   >     percentage:          99.0286%
   >     capacity:            43.4667%
   >     technology:          lithium-ion
   >   History (charge):
   >     1354023683  99.029  discharging
3. 1 minute later:

   > native-path: /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:02/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0
   >   vendor:               SANYO
   >   model:                UM08B32
   >   power supply:         yes
   >   updated:              Tue Nov 27 15:42:31 2012 (17 seconds ago)
   >   has history:          yes
   >   has statistics:       yes
   >   battery
   >     present:             yes
   >     rechargeable:        yes
   >     state:               discharging
   >     energy:              20.9196 Wh
   >     energy-empty:        0 Wh
   >     energy-full:         21.1248 Wh
   >     energy-full-design:  48.6 Wh
   >     energy-rate:         13.5432 W
   >     voltage:             11.753 V
   >     time to empty:       1.5 hours
   >     percentage:          99.0286%
   >     capacity:            43.4667%
   >     technology:          lithium-ion
   >   History (charge):
   >     1354023683  99.029  discharging
   >   History (rate):
   >     1354023751  13.543  discharging
4. 2-3 minutes later:

   > native-path: /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:02/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0
   >   vendor:               SANYO
   >   model:                UM08B32
   >   power supply:         yes
   >   updated:              Tue Nov 27 15:45:06 2012 (20 seconds ago)
   >   has history:          yes
   >   has statistics:       yes
   >   battery
   >     present:             yes
   >     rechargeable:        yes
   >     state:               discharging
   >     energy:              20.2824 Wh
   >     energy-empty:        0 Wh
   >     energy-full:         21.1248 Wh
   >     energy-full-design:  48.6 Wh
   >     energy-rate:         13.7484 W
   >     voltage:             11.545 V
   >     time to empty:       1.5 hours
   >     percentage:          96.0123%
   >     capacity:            43.4667%
   >     technology:          lithium-ion
   >   History (charge):
   >     1354023906  96.012  discharging
   >     1354023844  97.035  discharging
   >   History (rate):
   >     1354023906  13.748  discharging
   >     1354023875  12.992  discharging
   >     1354023844  13.284  discharging
5. 10 minutes later:

   > native-path: /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:02/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0
   >   vendor:               SANYO
   >   model:                UM08B32
   >   power supply:         yes
   >   updated:              Tue Nov 27 15:54:24 2012 (28 seconds ago)
   >   has history:          yes
   >   has statistics:       yes
   >   battery
   >     present:             yes
   >     rechargeable:        yes
   >     state:               discharging
   >     energy:              18.1764 Wh
   >     energy-empty:        0 Wh
   >     energy-full:         21.1248 Wh
   >     energy-full-design:  48.6 Wh
   >     energy-rate:         13.2948 W
   >     voltage:             11.268 V
   >     time to empty:       1.4 hours
   >     percentage:          86.0429%
   >     capacity:            43.4667%
   >     technology:          lithium-ion
   >   History (charge):
   >     1354024433  86.043  discharging
   >   History (rate):
   >     1354024464  13.295  discharging
   >     1354024433  13.662  discharging
   >     1354024402  13.781  discharging

I noticed that between #2 and #3 (0 and 1 minutes after unplugging), while the battery still reports 99% charge and drops from 2:30 hr to 1:30 hr, the energy usage goes from 8.34 W to 13.54 W and the current_now increases, but shouldn't it be using less energy in battery mode since the screen is much dimmer and it's in power saving mode? (or is that normal behavior?)

It also seems to drain more quickly than what it predicts, especially with the 1-1.25 hour drop in the first minute of being unplugged, which seems odd.

What really concerns me is that Ubuntu 12.10 may not be properly managing the battery (with the sudden change in charge/life from 2:30 to 1:30 or 1:15 within a minute of unplugging), and that a new battery may quickly die under Ubuntu 12.10.

I'd greatly appreciate any advice/suggestions on what to do, and especially whether there's a way to get back the 1-1.5 hrs of battery life that were suddenly lost when changing from WinXp to Ubuntu 12.10.

Thanks :)

Comment: Not so much an "answer" per se, but you have to run powertop in the terminal. so

          sudo powertop

then while its running it should give you options to press specific keys to enable / disable certain functions.
Also, You could try uninstalling any and every program you're not actually using. In my experience some programs will run background processes and it seems to me that this absorbs more cpu time and therefore more power. Best of luck I'll be curious to see the "solutions".

Answer (score 2):

Your battery is shot and needs replaced:

```
energy-full: 21.1248 Wh
energy-full-design: 48.6 Wh
capacity: 43.4667%
```

This shows the battery is holding less than half of its design capacity.

```
voltage: 12.173 V
```

This is also off; the fully charged voltage should be 12.5 V.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it **needs** to be replaced but it should if you want full capacity again.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the answer of @psusi is right but I might have a workaround.

The fact that Windows runs longer on that battery indicates that it still has more capacity than Ubuntu calculated. If this is the case, it can run longer than the shown battery time. All you have to do is to disable the automatic shutdown on low power as explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210623/modify-actions-when-battery-is-critically-low/217874#217874).

If you do so your laptop will keep running even though Ubuntu shows 0% battery power. The only problem is you have no way to tell how long. At some point, it will turn off without warning. Besides not properly shutting down, you will lose unsaved data.

Comment: The capacity is measured by the battery itself, not Ubuntu.  The windows getting longer runtime is probably just remembered from when the battery was in better condition.

Comment: Of course, thanks for pointing that out. Corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I don't need the battery to have full capacity. I just need it to have the same or similar capacity that it had under Windows XP (a few *minutes* before I installed Ubuntu 12.10 and *immediately* lost 1 hour from the battery life). So, psusi, 2.5 hrs isn't "remembered" from when the battery was in better condition. Windows still has 2.5 hrs battery life and Ubuntu isn't utilizing this 2.5 hr capacity). So, the question remains - why Ubuntu 12.10 has 1 hour less battery time than Windows XP Pro does, and what to do about it? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

As said previously, your battery can only contain half its original capacity, but to get that 1 hour of Windows extra back into Ubuntu, install TLP in Ubuntu and restart. your battery life will DOUBLE