# Bettery life issue with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS amd 64 bit

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, power-management, battery

i have dell 5537 i5 4th Gen laptop.

> after installation of ubuntu 14.04 LTS amd 64 bit version on my laptop.
>
> my laptop battery life is decreasing  very quickly .and life bet-try is showing 1 hours max.
>
> while using Windows 7 / 8 , its working fine and battery life is 5-4 hours max.
>
> so, i want to use latest ubuntu but the battery life issue is very serious.
>
> please send me step by step for solving this issue with latest Ubuntu.
>
> or you can send me the US phone number or your personal US number, so i will call  you and you will help me on the spot if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot add comment

This is probably caused by your GPU. It runs and consumes battery. You have hybrid graphics so battery will last longer, 
but for this
you should install graphics drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I have an Asus laptop that had a usable battery in it, with windows I could get 35-40 minutes from it.
With Ubuntu I can get about 35-40 seconds(12.04 LTS, running a tab in Chromium and Libreoffice)
Here is my take on it:
Ubuntu does not have drivers for the various power supply optimizers that windows has.
If you have ever disassembled a Lion battery pack, you can see that each cell has its own terminals that connect to the computer.
However, I think that Ubuntu is utilizing one of those cells, which as a result has become severely overdrained(and damaged). 
It fails to detect the other cells and therefore does not use the bat pack's full capacity.
I read this thread:
[Battery life starts at 2:30 hrs (99%), but less than 1 minute later is only 1:30 hrs (99%)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222576/battery-life-starts-at-230-hrs-99-but-less-than-1-minute-later-is-only-130?rq=1)
and it may be a similar issue.

I am no tech nut. Just a teenager who really likes Ubuntu and spends a lot of time on my laptop and outside.

My battery life is horrid.
If it is bad-and you know you have battery left-
you can try this:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
dconf-editor
```

It will open up a text-editor like thing. 
If you already have dconf tools skip the first line of code.
I didn't so I included it.

go to 
    org > gnome > settings-daemon > plugins > power
and change the "critical battery action" value to nothing

This may give you quite a bit more battery life.
It may not.
Just something to try.

UPDATE: I am now doing this.
It increased the battery life signifigantly.
:)