# Ubuntu 16.04 battery percentage shutdown not working

Tags: power-management, shutdown, 16.04, battery

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Dell Inspiron and got an issue that my laptop is not shutdown even after battery is critical low and even after percentage action.

My dconf setting are as follow:

[image: Picture-of-Dconf Settings]

Any Help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried going into the system settings > power and picking power off where it it says when power is critically low?

Comment: Yes see my dconf settings

Answer (score 1):

As Steam gamer commented , you can try going in your Power Settings Menu.

In PowerSettings Menu , Select Hibernate/PowerOff when your system is critically low option.

Here is the screenshot :

[image]

Last night , I selected this option.

My system went to hibernate but when I started my system ,my battery percentage was 4%.

So critical action was not taken on my percentage-critical parameter (Set to 32%) and percentage-action parameter(set to 30).
Needless to say ,use-time-for-policy was also set to false.

Below is the screenshot for my dconf :

[image]

I am still trying to get this to work . I will update the answer if I find something that works perfectly.

I have not tried the laptop-mode-tools way as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195671/wont-hibernate-when-battery-critical?rq=1). I hope that would work.

But now I am looking if any slight change is required somewhere to get this to work.

Hope this helps!!