# Execute script on battery switch

Tags: bash, battery, scripts

I would like to have a bash script to be executed when I switch to battery alimentation, is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean when the battery is used or the battery falls to a particular energy level? Good primer on battery levels here http://askubuntu.com/questions/69556/how-to-check-battery-status-using-terminal

Comment: when it is used

Answer (score 1):

yes there is a way.

From the  [Advanced Power Management (APM) daemon
(apmd)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man8/apmd.8.html)  man-page . This is a program. so when you remove the battery automatically this program will run. so you can use a condition to check the status of this program. If condition done then you can run the script else you can wait until it will runs.

```
change power
              Invoked when the APM subsystem reports a change in power status,
              such as a switch from mains to battery power.
```

Comment: I read it may conflicts with acpi

Comment: and that acpi is advised

Comment: check it once ,  because conflict will happen if acpi and apmd doing the same process/job. but as I know acpi not having any functionality like change power.so there will be no conflict.

Comment: what about https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Acpid?