# How to restore battery status indicator in landscape mode?

Tags: 12.04, display, indicator, battery

On an Ubuntu 12.04 system, I rotated my beagle board screen display to landscape mode and now the battery status indicator applet is disappeared. Is there any simple applet program to display the battery status in Ubuntu or any possible way to show the battery status indicator applet?

Comment: If all you need is just to know battery percentage, and not intimidated of using terminal just a little bit, refer to my answer here and you also can read the whole post on this topic: http://askubuntu.com/a/501389/295286

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `indicator-power` is installed.

> sudo apt-get install indicator-power

If it's installed though then you can try re-installing it.

> sudo apt-get purge indicator-power
>
> sudo apt-get install indicator-power

UPDATE:

The whole indicator applet:Clone of the GNOME panel indicator applet

`sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete`

Unity Global Menu type applet: Clone of the GNOME panel indicator applet

`sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-appmenu`

Session applet: Clone of the GNOME panel indicator applet

`sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-session`

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Right click the panel if using Gnome-Classic or
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Right click the panel if using Gnome-Classic (No Effects)

Choose Add To Panel and add the following indicator

[image]

ALSO:

UPDATE2:

- `cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent |grep POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY`
- in `acpi`

`sudo apt-get install acpi`

`acpi -b`

produces kind of:

> Battery 0: Charging, 43%, 06:09:08 until charged

- `battery-status`

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:iaz/battery-status && sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install battery-status`

`/usr/lib/battery-status/battery-status --indicator`

Comment: have a look please at update.

Comment: it works before rotating the screen after rotating the screen the battery status disappeared

Comment: if anything wrong with the screen resolution in there then it might affect somehow so probably try installing `arandr` for better desktop configuring.