# BQ's Ubuntu Phone battery life

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I would like to ask people, who own new BQ's Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu edition about their experience with battery life. Or other people, what should I do, if there is any problem with mine. Because the battery life seems to me really really really low. I have to charge it everyday, even though I barely use it. I charge to 100%, go to sleep and when I wake up next morning, there is around 70% left. Is it normal, that it losts 30% of battery just by being there on my table? I go to school, the same, it's there in my pocket the whole day and when I get home, I have to charge it, because it won't last until the next morning.  Is there anything I can do or it's just normal with this phone / OS? This is basically the only thing that bothers me about BQ's Ubuntu Phone. Except that it's a great phone.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Part of the question could be if is it SW or HW problem. If the android version of BQ's Aquaris E4.5 is in the same situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are currently seeing excessive drain due to issues with GPS being overly active and the notification daemon keeping the system awake, along with a few other things.

The upcoming system update has a number of changes to greatly improve the battery life. We are working to release this update at the earliest possible time, sorry for the inconvenience.

A list of these fixes is at https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-products/+bugs?field.tag=battery&field.status%3Alist=FIXRELEASED

Comment: I installed updated just few minutes ago. So I hope it was the right update.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use it every day basically for seeing my mails, twitter, the news and some calls/sms, and with the wifi on at home or the 3G outside and the position off, my battery lasts for 24-36h.
It's like full in the morning and about 40-50% left at night

Answer (score 1):

I have similar "features", my battery lasts about 24 hrs with normal use and it is really not influenced by the screen as much as it is by the wi-fi and 3G antenna.
This obviously means that during a 8hr sleep it goes down by about 30% (8 hours is about 1/3 of a day, 24 hours ;) ) if I do not switch off wi-fi and 3G.

I have experienced that the wi-fi is the thing that uses the most battery. Try turning it off when you don't use it; this will save a lot of power.

And, if you can, remember to switch to 2G whenever you don't need 3G.

Comment: WiFi and 3G is turned off of course. I'm literally talking about the phone just "being". It just has to wake me up in the morning. It even seems to me like it does not matter if the WiFi is turned on or not. I wanted the battery to fully run down as suggested in the manual. The phone was able to let me play a game for about half an hour until it run down from 5% to 0.

Comment: Using [this method](http://askubuntu.com/a/102863/29595) you can have informations on the battery. Can you check whether its capacity is still at 100%?

Comment: upower -e gave me /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_battery. upower -i says that is has no statistics and history, so I did not show much.

Comment: Does `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_battery` says that?

Comment: Here http://i.imgur.com/cF6OfR6.png Updated date is also weird (my time and date is set correctly)

Comment: Interesting! Maybe it's better if you signal the problem on the IRC channel [#ubuntu-touch](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=ubuntu-touch), I would not exclude a manufacturing problem...

Comment: Not too happy about it, but I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using mine for a while now.
After 2 days of use It usually still has about 20-5% battery left.

My usage pattern:

- Hook it up to the charger before I go to sleep (I turn of the wifi at night).
- Turn on the wifi in the morning.
- Use it normally during the day - 3-4 calls/day, wifi off if I'm on the PC, wifi on during other times. Bluetooth is on during commute time (a little less than 1h/day)
- Turn of wifi while I sleep
- Same cylce next day - but at the second night I have to charge it again.

Notes:

I normally do some browsing on the phone during the day, but it's mostly email, [hangups](https://github.com/tdryer/hangups) via terminal and a few scopes.

Comment: And you let it charge while you sleep or just charge it to full and disconnect it from AC?

Comment: I just unplug it when I wake up. It remains plugged the whole night.

Answer (score 1):

My Ubuntu phone has good days and bad days. Often areas of poor reception and losing signal+finding new networks drains the battery, which is probably why it drains quicker in the countryside and underground.

I find turning off services like location and GPS can help, and wifi is a massive drain.

I know the next RTM release is going to bring some improvements to battery life, should be out in the coming weeks.

Answer (score 1):

My battery sucks hairy ones, and it appears to be getting worse. Last night I charged it around evening time, I made sure to do all my downloads + browsing while charging so as not to overwork when off charger. It is now at 20% and says "last full charge **14 hours**", I always have GPS off & usually before bed I make sure to close all apps, but left habitRPG on last night, perhaps this is why it is so bad today...

I like this phone, but there are a few frustrating issues, I am hoping the positives will out weigh the negatives.

Is there any battery saving app about that will help save power? I had one on my android that I could set up schedules: Wifi, bluetooth, GPS off at night and back on in morning. A scope or app that tells you where power is going would be good, with option to close power drainers.

Comment: I have not found such app. I'm still waiting for the mentioned update and hoping it will get better. Because this is basically the only thing that bothers me about the phone.

Comment: Most recent update is definitely helping, currently running phone for 2 days, still above 30% wi-fi on too! At the minute it looks twice the battery duration, perhaps more. This is on my BQ 4.5

Comment: I can confirm that. Update totally helped.