# Battery doesn't charge from Dell

Tags: dell, battery, 16.10

I have  a Dell Latitude E6400. I installed it Ubuntu 16.10 and if it keeps connected doesn't have problem, but doesn't charges the battery. What can i do?

Comment: Do two things to trouble shoot, `test the charger on another computer`, and also `test another charger on your computer`

Comment: Look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/69556/how-to-check-battery-status-using-terminal and try to add information...