# Urgent notifications not showing up in fullscreen mode

Tags: gnome, 18.04, notification, fullscreen

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. I did a clean install, all is nice and quite stable, but I can't see urgent notifications in fullscreen mode (es. YouTube videos in Google Chrome, movies on MPV, Totem or VLC). I tried using `--urgency-critical` and `-u critical`, and I saw they're working in normal use as I have to click on the X button to remove them, but this command doesn't put them on top like in 17.10. I don't understand if it's a Gnome Shell bug or I have to do something new.
It's really annoying because I don't see the battery low notification and my laptop switches off everytime I watch a movie. I have to control myself, not comfortable, really.
Anyone knows a workaround or something?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is very annoying. For workaround, I use [`zenity`](https://github.com/GNOME/zenity)'s `warning` dialog-box. It has the benefit of popping up even over full-screen applications:

```
zenity --warning --text='Battery Low' --no-wrap
```

---

Getting the current battery percentage programmatically via script is very easy, but will require a little bit of research on your part, because of variability among systems and manufacturers. Start from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69556/how-to-check-battery-status-using-terminal).

---

Here is my script setup:

This is **batteryLevel.sh** :

```
#!/bin/bash

upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1 | grep percentage | sed -r 's/[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1/'
```

This is **batteryStatus.sh** :

```
#!/bin/bash

upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1 | grep state | sed -r 's/.*\:\ +(.*)/\1/'
```

Finally, this is **batteryInfoNotify.sh** :

```
#!/bin/bash

upperThreshold=99
lowerThreshold=20

echo upperThreshold=$upperThreshold
echo lowerThreshold=$lowerThreshold

zenity --info --text='Battery level monitoring started...' --no-wrap 2>&1 >/dev/null

while [[ true ]]; do
    status=$(~/Scripts/batteryStatus.sh)
    level=$(~/Scripts/batteryLevel.sh)
    msg="Battery Level now is $level%"

    echo "Battery $level% and $status"

    case $status in
        charging | fully-charged)
            if [[ $level -gt $upperThreshold ]]; then
                echo 'Upper threshold crossed...'
                zenity --warning --text="$msg" --no-wrap --timeout=8 >/dev/null 2>&1
                espeak -v en+m7 -p 60 "$msg"
            fi
            ;;
        discharging)
            if [[ $level -lt $lowerThreshold ]]; then
                echo 'Lower threshold crossed...'
                zenity --warning --text="$msg" --no-wrap --timeout=8 >/dev/null 2>&1
                espeak -v en+m7 -p 60 "$msg"
            fi
            ;;
        *)
            echo unexpected battery status
            ;;
    esac

    sleep 30s
done
```

All of these are in my `~/Scripts` and `batteryInfoNotify.sh` is called at session startup everytime because I set it up so in `GNOME Startup Appications`.

Comment: very good answer, really useful !