# Ubuntu shuts down on battery

Tags: 20.04, gnome, bluetooth, shutdown, iwlwifi

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed. I'm using a laptop, Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Extreme 2nd gen. When plugged in, there is no problem. But, when I use the laptop NOT plugged in (on battery), then it shuts down even it shows around 85% battery. Suddenly, it shows 1% and gives notification (battery low system will shut down). Then I plug in the battery cable and reboot system, it works perfectly fine. I looked at the time it shut down (13:50) and after I boot the system, I checked `/var/logs/syslog` and saved it. I could not understand what is the problem? Is it Bluetooth? Here are the logs;

```
Jun 29 13:50:02 aydin /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1827]: dbus-daemon[1827]: [session uid=125 pid=1827] Activating service name='ca.desrt.dconf' requested by ':1.5' (uid=125 pid=1912 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Jun 29 13:50:02 aydin /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1827]: dbus-daemon[1827]: [session uid=125 pid=1827] Successfully activated service 'ca.desrt.dconf'
Jun 29 13:50:06 aydin gnome-shell[2543]: Source ID 974236 was not found when attempting to remove it
Jun 29 13:50:06 aydin gnome-shell[2543]: Source ID 974329 was not found when attempting to remove it
Jun 29 13:50:06 aydin gnome-shell[2543]: Source ID 975409 was not found when attempting to remove it
Jun 29 13:50:06 aydin gnome-shell[2543]: Could not create transient scope for PID 640955: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 640955 does not exist.
Jun 29 13:50:06 aydin gnome-shell[2543]: Could not create transient scope for PID 640956: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 640956 does not exist.
Jun 29 13:50:06 aydin gnome-shell[2543]: Could not create transient scope for PID 640957: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 640957 does not exist.
Jun 29 13:50:06 aydin gnome-shell[2543]: Could not create transient scope for PID 640958: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 640958 does not exist.
Jun 29 13:50:06 aydin gnome-shell[2543]: Could not create transient scope for PID 640959: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 640959 does not exist.
Jun 29 13:50:06 aydin gnome-shell[2543]: Could not create transient scope for PID 640960: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 640960 does not exist.
Jun 29 13:50:06 aydin gnome-shell[2543]: Could not create transient scope for PID 640961: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 640961 does not exist.
Jun 29 13:50:06 aydin gnome-shell[2543]: g_dbus_connection_emit_signal: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
Jun 29 13:50:15 aydin gnome-shell[2543]: ../clutter/clutter/clutter-actor.c:10558: The clutter_actor_set_allocation() function can only be called from within the implementation of the ClutterActor::allocate() virtual function.
Jun 29 13:50:22 aydin systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service: Succeeded.
Jun 29 13:50:22 aydin gnome-shell[2543]: gnome-shell: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
Jun 29 13:50:22 aydin systemd[1]: Stopping Session 2 of user yalin.
Jun 29 13:50:22 aydin systemd[1]: Stopping Session c1 of user gdm.
Jun 29 13:50:22 aydin pulseaudio[2258]: X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
Jun 29 13:50:22 aydin systemd[1]: Removed slice system-clean\x2dmount\x2dpoint.slice.
Jun 29 13:50:22 aydin systemd[1]: Removed slice system-getty.slice.
Jun 29 13:50:22 aydin kernel: [280184.128652] rfkill: input handler enabled
Jun 29 13:50:22 aydin systemd[2252]: Stopped target GNOME X11 Session (session: ubuntu).
Jun 29 13:50:22 aydin gdm3: Tried to look up non-existent conversation gdm-launch-environment
Jun 29 13:50:22 aydin systemd[2252]: Stopped target GNOME Session.
Jun 29 13:50:22 aydin bluetoothd[1202]: Terminating
Jun 29 13:50:22 aydin systemd[2252]: Stopped target GNOME X11 Session.
Jun 29 13:50:22 aydin ModemManager[1336]: <info>  Caught signal, shutting down...
Jun 29 14:01:53 aydin systemd-modules-load[348]: Inserted module 'lp'
Jun 29 14:01:53 aydin systemd-modules-load[348]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Jun 29 14:01:53 aydin systemd-modules-load[348]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Jun 29 14:01:53 aydin systemd-modules-load[348]: Inserted module 'v4l2loopback'
```

*note: aydin is my pc name and yalin is user.*

Comment: You possibly need a new battery. Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69556/how-do-i-check-the-batterys-status-via-the-terminal#102863) help?

Comment: I agree with @Raffles: It's probably time for a new battery. They have a limited life time and a limited number of charge/discharge cycles. After some years, they need to be replaced.

Comment: And just as a matter of interest always try to get an original battery. The copies don't last long at all.

Comment: Might be your battery. With my T450s, for example, the battery I had originally for it went belly up, and anytime I would try to run the laptop off of battery power it would shut itself down. Had to get a new battery for it to resolve the issue and be able to separate it from the charger again